# Delete a row after insert with trigger mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-delete

I'm trying to create a trigger to delete my IP from my internal app (as a dev half of the logs are mine) to keep the log cleaner. To do that I constantly go and query manually in phpMyAdmin:

```
DELETE FROM `log` WHERE `ip1` = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
```

I tried creating a trigger in phpMyAdmin with that code but I keep getting the syntax error. I tried with both `old.` and `new.`, also `before` and `after`, nothing works I get this error:

> Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1442 Can't update table 'log' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

(the trigger is accepted in phpMyAdmin but when I access the app I get that).

As I read the reason it's because you can't use delete on a insert trigger, because the table gets locked in the first place, etc., but I don't find any way around it to achieve what it seemed to me like a simple task... sorry my knowledge on MySQL is quite limited. Surely there must be a way...

Comment: Instead of inserting in that table with an `INSERT` statement, call a `PROCEDURE` that will do both the `INSERT` and `DELETE`. That will work.

Comment: My thoughts would be to either use a **`BEFORE ROW`** trigger to check the IP address and skip the insertion of the row (I don't know if you can do that in MySQL), or use an **`AFTER STATEMENT`** trigger to delete all rows with your IP address.

Comment: The procedure seems like the correct way to do it, unfortunately I don't have a clue about how to create it at the moment. I'll investigate a bit more and see if I can do it that way.

Comment: There is no good way to do stop an insert in a trigger in mysql, but you can just [create an event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) to regularly execute your delete query on a schedule.